# Agregar strings a arreglo mediante una funcion

Tags: c

Tengo un problema con agregar strings a un arreglo. La idea del algoritmo es cargar los datos de un archivo en 3 arreglos distintos y mediante 1 funcion poder agregar mas datos en cada arreglo.
La cantidad de datos me aumenta cada vez que agrego pero lo agrega en blanco.

```
// PARA CARGAR EL ARCHIVO
void CARGA(char palEsp[10000][50], char palIng[10000][50], int cant[10000], int *cantPal) {
    int e=0, f, g;
    FILE * a1;
    a1 = fopen("espaingl.txt", "r");
    while( !feof(a1) ) { // MIENTRAS NO LLEGUE AL FINAL DEL ARCHIVO
    fscanf(a1, "%s %s %d", palEsp[e], palIng[e], &cant[e]); // ESCANEO CADA PALABRA Y LA CANTIDAD CON SUS TIPOS DE DATOS
        printf("%s %s %d \n", palEsp[e], palIng[e], cant[e]); // IMPRIMO POR PANTALLA TODO
        e++; // AUMENTO 1 A E POR CADA VEZ QUE EJECUTA EL WHILE PARA CONTAR LA CANT DE PAL
    }
    fclose(a1); // CIERRO ARCHIVO
    *cantPal=e; // GUARDO E EN CANT PAL
}
```

La subrutina anterior carga los datos en 3 arreglos

```
// AÑADIR PALABRA AL ARREGLO Y MOSTRARLO
void ADDPALABRAESP(int cant[10000], char palEsp[10000][50], char palIng[10000][50], int *cantpal){
    char trad[50], palab[50];
    int bandera=0;
    int cantidad = *cantpal;
    printf("Ingrese la palabra que desea agregar:\n");
    scanf(" %s", palab);
    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        if (strcmp(palab, palEsp[i])==0)
        {
            printf("La palabra %s ya esta en el traductor.\n", palab);
            bandera=1;
        }
    }
    if (bandera==0)
    {
        cantidad++;
        palEsp[cantidad-1] == palab;
        printf("Ingrese la traduccion:\n");
        scanf(" %s", trad);
        palIng[cantidad-1] == trad;
        cant[cantidad-1] == 1;
        printf("Se ha anadido la palabra %s al traductor.\n", palab);
        printf("Se ha anadido la traduccion %s al traductor.\n", trad);
    }
    *cantpal = cantidad;
    bandera==0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) {
        printf("%s %s %d\n", palEsp[i], palIng[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Discuple, cometi un error con las etiquetas...

Comment: No hay problema! En cuanto a la pregunta, alguna idea?

Comment: `while( !feof(...) )` siempre está mal, [mirar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). En cuanto a la pregunta, no la entiendo del todo. ¿Qué debería hacer exactamente el programa? ¿Qué observas exactamente? ¿Podrías publicar un [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La cantidad de datos me aumenta cada vez que agrego pero lo agrega en blanco.

No es que lo agregue en blanco... es que estás **comparando** en vez de **asignando**

```
palEsp[cantidad-1] == palab;
//                 ~~ COMPARACION
printf("Ingrese la traduccion:\n");
scanf(" %s", trad);
palIng[cantidad-1] == trad;
//                 ~~ COMPARACION
cant[cantidad-1] == 1;
//               ~~ COMPARACION
```

En cualquier caso, la asignación únicamente te iba a servir con el array de enteros. Para copiar arrays de caracteres hay que usar funciones como `strcpy`. Aunque claro, la palabra en inglés podrías almacenarla directamente en el propio array:

```
strcpy(palEsp[cantidad-1], palab);
printf("Ingrese la traduccion:\n");
scanf(" %s", palIng[cantidad-1]);
cant[cantidad-1] = 1;
```

Por otro lado, nota que si el incremento de `cantidad` lo haces **después** de guardar las palabras, te ahorras ese incómodo `-1` en el acceso a cada array:

```
//cantidad++; <<-- lo quitamos del principio

strcpy(palEsp[cantidad], palab);
printf("Ingrese la traduccion:\n");
scanf(" %s", palIng[cantidad]);
cant[cantidad] = 1;

++cantidad; // <<--- y lo ponemos al final
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pude solucionarlo con strcpy.